# Horizontal scroll bar for NSText

Tags: cocoa, scrollbar, nstextview

ALL,

I'm looking at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextUILayer/Tasks/TextInScrollView.html), but it is not clear to me:

> To set up both horizontal and vertical scroll bars, use the statements
>   in Listing 4 in place of the corresponding statements in the previous
>   listings.

It does not say, however, which block (or code) needs to be replaced.

Could someone shed some light please?

I'm looking for a way to display the horizontal scroll bar for the NSTextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apple documentation is not written in such a way that it would be easy for a non-native English speaker to understand.

What the documentation is saying is that instead of *in addition* to the code that's in listings 1 2 & 3, *replace* the similar (or "corresponding") lines from the previous listings with what you see in listing 4.

In other words, combining listings 1, 2, 3 and then overwriting what's in listing 4, should end up with something like this:

```
NSScrollView *scrollview = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[theWindow contentView] frame]];

NSSize contentSize = [scrollview contentSize];

[scrollview setBorderType:NSNoBorder];

[scrollview setHasVerticalScroller:YES];

[scrollview setHasHorizontalScroller:YES];

[scrollview setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];

theTextView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, contentSize.width, contentSize.height)];

[theTextView setMinSize:NSMakeSize(0.0, contentSize.height)];

[theTextView setMaxSize:NSMakeSize(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX)];

[theTextView setVerticallyResizable:YES];

[theTextView setHorizontallyResizable:YES];

[theTextView setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable)];

[[theTextView textContainer] setContainerSize:NSMakeSize(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX)];

[[theTextView textContainer] setWidthTracksTextView:NO];

[scrollview setDocumentView:theTextView];

[theWindow setContentView:scrollview];

[theWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];

[theWindow makeFirstResponder:theTextView];
```

Comment: thank you, works like a charm. But Apple documentation is a different issue. ;-)